# Graded version of Baer's Criterion

Tags: modules, ac.commutative-algebra, injective-modules

Baer's  Criterion for injectiveness of modules says: "An $R$-module $E$ is injective iff for all ideals $I$ of $R$, every homomorphism $f\colon I \to E$ can be extended to $R$." I wonder if there is a graded version for this? I mean:

Let $R$ be a graded ring. Let $M$ be a graded $R$-module.

> If $Ext_R^1(R/I,E)=0$ for all homogeneous ideals $I$ of $R$ then $Ext_R^1(M,E)=0$ for every graded $R$-module $M$?

Comment: Can you not just copy the usual proof inserting the word "graded" everywhere?

Comment: @Eric: No - cf. my answer. But in some way also Yes - using the right interpretation of "graded Ext" and "graded R"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the correct graded version you have to observe all possible shifts. More precisely:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group, let $R$ be a $G$-graded ring, and let $M$ be a $G$-graded $R$-module. Then, the following statements are equivalent:
>
> *(i)* $M$ is injective;
>
> *(ii)* For every $g\in G$, every monomorphism $v\colon N\rightarrow R(g)$ and every morphism $w\colon N\rightarrow M$ there is a morphism $u\colon R(g)\rightarrow M$ such that $u\circ v=w$.

(Note that in the above, "morphism" means morphism in the category of $G$-graded $R$-modules.)

In order to proof this you have to observe that the category of $G$-graded $R$-modules is an AB5-category and that $\bigoplus_{g\in G}R(g)$ is a generator of this category, and then you can apply Lemma 1 in Section 1.10 of Grothendieck's Tohoku paper ([Link](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tmj/1178244839)).

Comment: I added a link to the Tohoku paper (where you can also find a definition of AB5).

Comment: I do not know of any translation. But do not fear - it is not french but maths!

Comment: Michael Barr has an English translation available here: http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/gk.pdf